# Including mercurial extensions from eggs

Tags: python, mercurial, distutils, egg, hgrc

Is there some way to import an extension from an `.egg` file? For example `hggit` installs itself as `hg_git-0.2.4-py2.5.egg`, which cannot be listed under `[extensions]` directly, or it's interpreted as a standard `.py` file.

Is there some way to include that file as an extension?

Alternatively, is there some way to install `hg-git` manually in a way that doesn't create `.egg` file, but an unpacked directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the egg is installed on your Python module path (aka: you easy_installed it), just do:

```
name_of_extension=
```

in the extensions part of your .hgrc